# SQL Server to Oracle | Date format error

Tags: sql-server, oracle10g, date-format

I'm trying to import data from a SQL Server database to Oracle. But I'm having a problem in date conversion, this is the SQL Server date (time stamp) that appears in `.cvs` file.

```
2008-01-09 15:52:21.483
```

I'm trying to figure out the correct date format:

```
select TO_DATE('2008-01-09 15:52:21.483','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9') from dual
```

But this is giving me an error:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
select TO_DATE('2008-01-09 15:52:21.483','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF9') from dual
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01821: date format not recognized
01821. 00000 -  "date format not recognized"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Can someone explain be the correct date format for this time stamp.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle `date` type doesn't support fractions of second. If you need them - you need to create `timestamp` instead:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP('2008-01-09 15:52:21.483','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9')
  from dual
```

Comment: @MMRUser: the query I've given works for me in both Oracle 10gr2 and 11gr2

Comment: Yes but my column types are DATE, so putting this date format (when importing data from csv) really doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @MMRUser: then ask your question in other way. In the way you asked the only answer - is to change type.

Comment: I have asked my question again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309450/importing-data-from-csv-file