# Importing data from csv file

Tags: oracle, date-format, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to import some data (using oracle sql developer) from a `.csv` file but I'm getting an error as :-

`Verifying if the Date columns have date formats FAILED Date columns` ... column names

the date in my `.csv` file is :

```
2008-01-09 15:59:23.187
```

I have tried giving this format but it doesn't work (in the data importing wizard)

```
yyyy-mm-dd HH24:mi:ss.ff3
```

I'm trying to figure out a solution expecting some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test right now but I'm taking a guess: the format is not a DATE format but a TIMESTAMP format. Consider:

```
SQL> select to_date('2008-01-09 15:59:23.187', 
  2                 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:mi:ss.ff3') from dual;

ORA-01821: date format not recognized

SQL> select to_timestamp('2008-01-09 15:59:23.187', 
  2                      'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:mi:ss.ff3') ts from dual;

TS
-------------------------------------------------
09/01/08 15:59:23,187000000
```

If this is the same error that SQL Dev encounters, you could import in a timestamp column.

Comment: Please, I am having the same problem, and indeed I do want to import into a timestamp column. But how do I import into a timestamp column? How do I specify the format?

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle Date](http://psoug.org/reference/datatypes.html)'s can only store to seconds, you will need to use the timestamp.

Using a timestamp works fine (date fails with error of "Fractional seconds format element not allowed in DATE formatting")

```
create table test2(cola number(1), colB varchar2(5), colD timestamp);

csv file:
colA, colB, colD
"1","a","2008-01-09 :15:59:23.187"
"2","b","2009-02-10 :16:48:32.188"
"3","c","2012-03-11 :17:37:41.189"

"Import Data" in SQL Developer 3.0.03 using colD format of yyyy-mm-dd HH24:mi:ss.ff3
select * from test2;
COLA                   COLB  COLD                      
---------------------- ----- ------------------------- 
1                      a     09-JAN-08 03.59.23.187000000 PM 
2                      b     10-FEB-09 04.48.32.188000000 PM 
3                      c     11-MAR-12 05.37.41.189000000 PM
```